Summary statistics group by values in a range
I want to produce summary data from something like the following:
Col A - Col B
1 - 15
4 - 8
7 - 20
9 - 5
Let's say the ranges I want for my summary data is 1-5 and 6-10 for column A, summing on colB. So, how would I produce the following code?
Range | 1-5, 6-10
Sum(B) | 23, 25
The "query" function will break down everything (i.e. 1-5 becomes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Slightly expanding Michal's, using Excel 2021 and higher:
Enter in the first cell, E2 in the example
=LET(
    a, A1:A4,
    b, B1:B4,
    range, D2:D3,
    from, LEFT(range, FIND("-", range) - 1),
    to, RIGHT(range, LEN(range) - FIND("-", range)),
    SUMIFS(b, a, ">=" & from, a, "<=" & to)
)



The simplest way is to use SUMIFS:

=SUMIFS(B:B, A:A, ">=1", A:A, "<=5"), etc


Using the QUERY function, the formula in cell G2 is;

=QUERY(A2:B,"Select Sum(B) Where A>=" & E2 & " And A<= " & E3 & " Label Sum(B) 'QUERY RESULT'")


Or, you can use SUMPRODUCT function, where cells E2 and E3 are housing lower and upper bounds

=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A<=E3)*(A2:A>=E2)*(B2:B))


Or, if cell E5 is containing the text 6-10 as the lower and upper bounds, then again using the QUERY function;

=QUERY(A2:B,"Select Sum(B) Where A>=" & INDEX(SPLIT(E5,"-"),1) & " And A<= " & INDEX(SPLIT(E5,"-"),2) & " Label Sum(B) 'QUERY RESULT'")

.

